# Proc reg using by variable (month): How do you take average of all coefficients across all months?

Tags: sas, regression

How do you take an average of the coefficients across all months?

Please refer to this question earlier

[How do I perform regression by month on the same SAS data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915278/how-do-i-perform-regression-by-month-on-the-same-sas-data-set/59816105#59816105)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform regression by month on the same SAS data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915278/how-do-i-perform-regression-by-month-on-the-same-sas-data-set)

Comment: You can use the ODS (Output Delivery System) of SAS to store the estimated regression coefficients for each regression, stack those datasets into a single dataset and compute the average by coefficient name (e.g. using `PROC MEANS`).
For more information on ODS, please check the documentation. A helpful mechanism to get a list of the available output datasets for a particular procedure is to enclose the procedure between an `ods trace on;` and an `ods trace off;` statement, run the proc (including those statements) and check the log for the information generated by `ods trace`.

Comment: Show anything you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the linked question provide the code to get the estimates in a data set. Then you would run a PROC MEANS on the saved data set to get the averages. But you could also run the model without which a variable to get the monthly estimates alone. In general, it isn't common to average parameter estimates this way, except in a bootstrapping process.